# International and EU passport, which do i use for living rights?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, citizenship, eu-citizens, dual-citizenship

I'm asking on behalf of my girlfriend. She holds an Italian passport and a Uruguayan passport.  She's looking to either move to or study in the UK to live with me.  In regard to living in the UK or working here, can she use her Italian passport and therefore enter as an EU citizen in accordance with EU law?

She lives in Uruguay. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If she wants to permanently move in it's advised for her to move in before March 29 using her Italian citizenship, that way her status would more secure.

Answer (score 2):

> can she use her Italian passport and therefore enter as an EU [citizen] and abide by the EU laws?

Yes she can, but with the UK's looming departure from the EU it would be best if she gets there before the end of March in case the deal falls through.

If the deal passes then it looks like the deadline would be the end of 2020.